# ListView with Load More Button and Circle ProgressBar

Tags: java, android, listview

I spent an hour trying to add "Load More" `Button` and indeterminate `ProgressBar` to the footer of my `ListView`.

**The supposed scinario works like this:**

When the button is clicked, `ProgressBar` is shown while `AsyncTask` is downloading 20 items. when the items are inserted to the `ListView`, the `ProgressBar` dismisses and the `Button` appears again in the footer. 
I come to the following solution and would be nice if you have better solution:

layout/progress_bar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProgressBar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/load_progress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:indeterminate="true"
     />
```

And assuming you have the following fields in the Activity:

```
private ListView listview;
private Button loadMoreButton;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
```

after preparing your list view add the footer like this, (at the end of the `activity.onCreate()`):

```
    loadMoreButton = new Button(this);
    loadMoreButton.setText("Load More");
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.progress_bar, null);

    loadMoreButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //downloadItems();
            listview.removeFooterView(loadMoreButton);
            listview.addFooterView(progressBar);

        }
    });
```

When the data is ready (either first page or subsequent pages), call the following after adapter update.

```
        //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    listview.removeFooterView(progressBar);
    listview.addFooterView(loadMoreButton);
```

If you have better solutions, please share it in the answers.

Comment: Instead of showing button to load more you can check on ScrollStateChange weather user is at bottom or not,
if found last index of item then you can show progress at footer and when loading complete remove it and show your data

Comment: I want to make the user click **Load More** to reduce number of calls to the server in case he kept scrolling all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to a solution without adding/removing the footer. Just put the two views (Load More Button and ProgressBar) in LinearLayout. Add the linearlayout as listview footer for first time only. Then change between the button and progressbar by changing visibility property.

Here is the updated code:

layout/list_footer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/load_more_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:text="Load More"/>

<ProgressBar android:id="@+id/load_progress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:visibility="gone"
        android:indeterminate="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

call this method at the end of Activity.onCreate() to add footer and handle button click (load data, hide button and show progress).

```
 private void prepareListFooter() {

    View view = (View) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.list_footer, null);


    loadMoreButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.load_more_button);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.load_progress);
    listview.addFooterView(view);
    loadMoreButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //downloadMore();
            loadMoreButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
}
```

also this code after adapter change to show the button and hide the progress.

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
loadMoreButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing and adding a view as footer.. you can have both button and progressbar in the same footer view and make visibility VISIBLE and Visibility GONE according to the requirement.

Comment: I tried to use `View.setVisiblity(View.GONE)`. But because I added two footers Button footer and ProgressBar footer to the listview, the listview save the space of the each footer even if the view is GONE.
When a view GONE, its space remains appearing above or below the visible view.